younger generation & young generation
According to Cambridge

Say:  The younger generation often lacks ambition.
Don’t say:    The young generation often lacks ambition.

why can't we say young generation?

It's just that younger is more usual in this context (meaning 'younger than I am'!).

Because youth as a property is transient. As an example, there was a time when my own generation was young, but today? Not so much.
Relative youth is different. If, at any point in time, some generation G is younger than another generation G’, then G will forever remain younger than G’.
One thing you could say using young is

The young often lack ambition

if you’re making a comment about humans in every era. Here, the young means “those who are young.” Or if you are referring only to those who are currently young, then you can say,

Today’s young often lack ambition.

In that case, young is modifying the (omitted) noun people.

We're the young generation, and we've got something to say (The Monkees, 1966)

Ah, @MichaelHarvey, how could I have forgotten that pinnacle of Western Civilization?

Paul - they made me want to puke when I was 14, and they still do now.

But @MichaelHarvey, Mrs. Brown has such a luvvly daw-tuh.

That damned Davy Jones' accent was nearly as fake as Jane Leeves (Daphne in Frasier). I know Jones came from Manchester (Leeves didn't, she's really from Essex!) but his accent was a concocted thing, stage-school Brit with a tiny hint of 'Northern'.
